# C Programming - Compiling Error: format '%s' expects type 'char *'

Tags: c

Source:

```
/*
* Name: Adam Chubbuck
* Date: 1/12/2014
* Class: CSC-1720
* Comment: Assignment #1 (Load-Sort-Print) v1
*/

#include<stdio.h>

int load(char fileName[], int array[]);
int sort(int array[], int length);
int print(int length, int array[]);

int main() {

   char fileName[100];
   int numList[300];
   int length;

   printf("File Name: ");
   scanf("%s", &fileName);

   length = print(sort(numList,load(fileName, numList)), numList);
   printf("\nLength: %i\n", length);

   printf("Finished execution.\n");

   return 0;
}

int load(char fileName[], int array[]) {

   FILE *input = fopen(fileName, "r");

   int length = 0, i = 0;

   if(input == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error accessing file.\n");
   } else {
      while(fscanf(input, "%i", &array[i]) != EOF) {
         i++;
         length++;
      }
   }

   fclose(input);
   return length;
}

int sort(int array[], int length) {
  int a, b, c;

  for (a = 0 ; a < ( length - 1 ); a++) {
    for (b = 0 ; b < length - a - 1; b++) {
      if (array[b] > array[b+1]) {
        c = array[b];
        array[b] = array[b+1];
        array[b+1] = c;
      }
    }
  }
   return length;
}

int print(int length, int array[]) {
   int i;

   printf("\n[NUMBERS]\n\n");
   for (i = 0; i< length; i++) {
      printf("[N]%i\n", array[i]);
   }
   return length;
}
```

I've read through similar topics on the issue and they advise that I remove the ampersand from the scanf statement, but when I do this and use I/O redirection to a file as follows, it seems to become stuck in an endless loop suggesting that it cannot assign the fileName character array a value.

```
./a.out < test.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Remove the &. It´s an compiler error, and it is solved if you remove it. The other thing is because you have more than one error...

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `char fileName[100]`.  This is almost equivalent to `char*` already<sup>1</sup>.  When you do

```
scanf("%s", &fileName);
```

it becomes equivalent to passing a `char**`.

<sup>1</sup>: You can google around for pointers vs. arrays to see what the differences are, but for passing parameters they're basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

In C an array is (almost<sup>1</sup>) the same as a pointer. So taking the address of an array gives the pointer to a pointer. Strings in C are just arrays of `char`. So in your statement

```
scanf("%s", &fileName);
```

You're passing the pointer to a pointer to `scanf` which is *not* what it expects. You should write just

```
scanf("%s", fileName);
```

However be advised, that this is a potential buffer overflow. `fileName` has only a limited amount of space and if what's entered is longer it will write beyond the length of `fileName`. The safe solution would be:

```
scanf("%99s", fileName);
```

---

[1] The notable difference is the behavior of the `sizeof` operator. If it's used on an array identifier it gives the actual size in `char`s occupied by the object. If it's used on a pointer it gives the size of the pointer type to the object.

Comment: @jweyrich: Yes this would be safe in this particular setup. However you normally want to pass the maximum length as a variable and not as a format string (you could create the format string with printf before). scanf unfortunately doesn't support the `*` format modifier to pass maximum length by variable. However the `m` modifier would make scanf perform the allocation as needed, but then you have to pass a (char**) and free the array later.

Comment: We agree. Hard-coding lengths in the format string is _bad_, but if he wants to use `scanf`, that's one thing he can do to stay safe. I beleive a safer alternative for his scenario would be `fgets`.

Answer (score 1):

Array names decays to pointer when pass to a function as an argument (some exception are there). `fileName` decays to a pointer to the first element of the array `fileName`. This is of type `char *`,i.e, it is the address of the first element of the array.
On the other hand, `&fileName` is the address of the entire array and is of type `char (*)[100]`.

`%s` specifier expects an argument of type `char *`. You need to pass `fileName` to `scanf` as argument.
When you pass `&fileName` as argument of `scanf` then compiler sees that it is not the argument of the expected type by the functon `scanf` and hence throws an error.
Change

```
scanf("%s", &fileName);
```

to

```
scanf("%s", fileName);
```

---

**Side Note:** Never use `scanf` or `gets` to read a string as it doesn't check the array bound.. Better to use `fgets`.

```
fgets(fileName, 100, stdin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays pass as pointers by default.  Use this instead...

```
scanf("%s", fileName);
```

Also I have read somewhere that you shouldn't use EOF to check that a file is finished being read.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, but please read the entire topic before offering advice. I am aware of how to resolve the issue by removing the ampersand, but that throws another error which has been described in my topic.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you use

```
scanf("%99", filename);
```

Where '99' is the maximum length you want to accept as input, and 'filename' has no ampersand (since you want to point to the first `char` of `filename`, not the address of `filename`)?

[cplusplus.com::scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)